# Unable to save data with php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I want to save the data with php. The program does not return an error. But to the database does not record.

**DOSYA ADI:signup.php**

**MY CODES:**

```
<form action="islem.php" method="post"> 
    Ad:<input type="text" name="bilgilerim_ad" placeholder="giriniz">
    Soyad:<input type="text" name="bilgilerim_soyad" placeholder="giriniz">
    Mail:<input type="text" name="bilgilerim_mail"placeholder="giriniz">
    Yaş:<input type="text" name="bilgilerim_yas" placeholder="giriniz">
    <button name="insertislemi" type="submit">Kayıt</button>
</form>
```

**DOSYA ADI:config.php**

**MY CODES**

```
<?php
    include 'baglan.php';

    if(isset($_POST['insertislemi'])){

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uyeler SET
      bilgilerim_ad =: bilgilerim_ad,
      bilgilerim_soyad =: bilgilerim_soyad,
      bilgilerim_mail =: bilgilerim_mail,
      bilgilerim_yas =: bilgilerim_yas,

    ");
    $insert = $query->execute(array(
        "bilgilerim_ad" => $_POST['bilgilerim_ad'],
        "bilgilerim_soyad" => $_POST['bilgilerim_soyad'],
        "bilgilerim_mail" => $_POST['bilgilerim_mail'],
        "bilgilerim_yas" => $_POST['bilgilerim_yas'],
    ));
    if ( $insert ){
        $last_id = $db->lastInsertId();
        print "insert işlemi başarılı!";
    }

}
?>
```

**MY CODES**

**CONNECTION FILE**

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
    //echo "giriş";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you made the database connection

Comment: yes I did, connected

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: Don't put spaces between the `:` and parameter name. Eg, this `bilgilerim_ad =: bilgilerim_ad` should be `bilgilerim_ad = :bilgilerim_ad`

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't a database. It's a tool to manage DBs

Comment: _"The program does not return an error"_ <- it would if you asked it to. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324601/283366

Comment: the action in the signup.php page points to another file other than the config.php ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first write `bilgilerim_ad =: bilgilerim_ad, ...` in your insert query, then `"bilgilerim_ad" => $_POST['bilgilerim_ad'],`.

There's a misplaced space, the datas are bound to `bilgilerim_ad` but you declared `: bilgilerim_ad`.

Replace your insert query by :

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uyeler SET
    bilgilerim_ad = :bilgilerim_ad,
    bilgilerim_soyad = :bilgilerim_soyad,
    bilgilerim_mail = :bilgilerim_mail,
    bilgilerim_yas = :bilgilerim_yas");
```

And bind your datas this way :

```
$insert = $query->execute(array(
    ":bilgilerim_ad" => $_POST['bilgilerim_ad'],
    ":bilgilerim_soyad" => $_POST['bilgilerim_soyad'],
    ":bilgilerim_mail" => $_POST['bilgilerim_mail'],
    ":bilgilerim_yas" => $_POST['bilgilerim_yas']));
```

This is out of topic, but in your php files where you are using **only** php code (the one that insert and the one that manage DB connection in example) do **not** close php tag `?>`. This can send unwanted characters to http header